# How to find similarity in document field MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

Given data that looks like this:

```
{'_id': 'foobar1',
 'about': 'similarity in comparison',
 'categories': ['one', 'two', 'three']}
{'_id': 'foobar2',
 'about': 'perfect similarity in comparison',
 'categories': ['one']}
{'_id': 'foobar3',
 'about': 'partial similarity',
 'categories': ['one', 'two']}
{'_id': 'foobar4',
 'about': 'none',
 'categories': ['one', 'two']}
```

I would like to find a way to get a similarity between a single item and all other items in the collection then return them in order of highest similarity. Similarity is based on number of words in common, there is already a function `int similar(String one, String two)`

For example: if I want the similarity list for `about` field of `foobar1`, it would return

`[{'_id': 'foobar2'}, {'_id': 'foobar3'}, {'_id': 'foobar4'}]`

I am doing this with morphia, but with just the mongoDB implementation, I could figure the rest out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you need to compute text similarity on the `about` field, one way to achieve this is to use [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

For example (in the `mongo` shell), if you create a text index on the `about` field:

```
db.collection.createIndex({about: 'text'})
```

you could execute a query such as (example taken from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#sort-by-text-search-score):

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: 'similarity in comparison'}}, {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}}).sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
```

With your example documents, the query should return something like:

```
{
  "_id": "foobar1",
  "about": "similarity in comparison",
  "score": 1.5
}
{
  "_id": "foobar2",
  "about": "perfect similarity in comparison",
  "score": 1.3333333333333333
}
{
  "_id": "foobar3",
  "about": "partial similarity",
  "score": 0.75
}
```

which are sorted by decreasing similarity score. Please note that unlike your example result, document `foobar4` is not returned because none of the queried words are present in `foobar4`.

Text indexes are considered a special type of index in MongoDB, and thus comes with some specific rules on its usage. For more details, please see:

- [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)
- [`$text` query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Comment: Can this be used if the about data contained larger text. for example a news article long maybe?

Comment: Yes the text index was designed to work with blobs of text.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I will try it out. If I face any issues, I will let you know.

Comment: is it possible to use "my own" implementation of an algorithm for calculating the similarity between my search term and the indices? e.g I want to apply the Levenshtein distance for similarity calculation between two strings/texts.

Comment: @MarkusG. no I don't think it's possible currently, since MongoDB uses the language to preprocess the words and remove stop words in an attempt to make the text index smaller. Levenshtein distance is a very different algorithm and I don't think it's language specific.