# How to narrow MySQL results for added PHP efficiency?

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I use similar_text to compare tens of thousands of rows from MySQL.

```
$mostSimilarText = "";
$mostSimilarPercent = 0;

//SELECT * FROM table

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ /* 10,000 results*/
    similar_text("hello world", $row["source"], $percentMatch);

    if($percentMatch > $mostSimilarPercent) {
        $mostSimilarPercent = $matchPercent;
        $mostSimilarText = $row["source"];
    }
}
//Now I have the most similar text and percentage.
```

That code works, but it runs very slowly, especially with LOADS of results. My goal is to optimize it.
I am trying to figure out how I can limit the MySQL results instead of `SELECT * FROM table`. This would improve efficiency.

I have experimented with using `LIKE 'hello world'`, but that will exclude results such as "hello word" (notice the missing L). I need to limit the MySQL results without completely elimating text that is more than 75% similar, more or less.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can do that to improve performance?

Comment: `similar_text` is extraordinarily heavy for a SQL database.. using is on every row will result in a time deficiency.. Have yo considered a flat database for the 'meta data' maybe ? To enhance your current DB?

Comment: Throwing in a flat DB which contains just he filterable term, will query quicker, throw in your SQL id's and you've got 2 transactions that will be quicker.. And thats a lazy way around it: Note: There are other concerns when trying to keep parity between databases so dont take this as a perfect answer

Comment: If flat db is not an option, mysql fulltext search will be better I would say.

Comment: @user3532758 It would be an improvement, but smells like an XY problem

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Flat will be 1000 times better as you suggested.

Comment: You can try full Text search and also take a look at fuzzy search https://sjhannah.com/blog/2014/11/03/using-soundex-and-mysql-full-text-search-for-fuzzy-matching/

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the flat DB. Could you post an answer with some more details regarding that?

Comment: @user3532758 A couple questions about full text. 1) Would it be significantly faster 2) Can it account of minor differences in text (ie."hello world" vs "hello word")?

Comment: @FrogGuacamole so flat is document based, not relational, for example you could have 1 json files with all the names that you want to filter, with their corresponding SQL id's, and just query the json..

Comment: I believe (will need to double check before I answer) SQL (assume mySQL because php) will allow JSON. so you could query the JSON itself to say : 'whats like this' in 1 file read its quicker - Thats meta-data.

Comment: @Pogrindis That sounds interesting. I would essentially have a copy of the table in JSON format and query from that JSON, correct? Why would that be faster than MySQL? I figured that relational DBs were more optimized for things like this.

Comment: >  Why would that be faster than MySQL? 
Because it only has to read 1 file.. Once its in memory, you can filter instant-ish

Comment: `I would essentially have a copy of the table in JSON ` - No - You have only a record of the ID's and what you want searchable. The reast is still in the SQL DB

Comment: Reading tens of thousands of records from a DB generally takes on the order of a few seconds. I still don't see why a flat file, and/or storing things in JSON, would help significantly when the real bottleneck is having to pass every record through the `similar_text()` function.

Comment: @kmoser you're not wrong, but I'm arguing for the right tool for the job, anything you're searching for, should not look to the original content (there are already calls for that who are busy) - With a good meta structure, the search would never reduce speed of the content providing API.

Comment: We'd have to know more details to be able to advise you on reasonable solutions. What is "runs very slowly"? Seconds? Minutes? Hours? How often is this query being run? Can you store the results so multiple requests against the same string don't have to be repeated? How do you define "75% similar, more or less"? Have you considered precomputing and caching [Levenshtein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: @kmoser +1 9/10 the problem is the query. But optimizing this query feels like solving for X when the problem is Y.

Comment: @kmoser You're right about similar_text being slow. My goal is to reduce the result set that get's passed into that function. It seems from what I've read here that using a flat DB is the fastest way to reduce the result set before using the similar_text function on what remains.

Comment: @kmoser the idea is not to rely on similar_text function. Flat dbs allow you to do that. Fulltext search too. Frog, yes it should be faster than your current implementation.

Comment: @user3532758 How is it that a flat DB allows for faster filtering when compared to loading the table data into memory and filtering in PHP (ie..similar_text)?

Comment: You will get the result you are looking for from the database itself. And to state broadly searching algos in flat dbs is optimised for performance, better than what php could offer.

Check this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365414/how-to-find-similarity-in-document-field-mongodb

Comment: @user3532758 How do I actually implement this flat DB? Do I need to install a no-sql database and somehow communicate with it through PHP?

Comment: I posted a more updated question on the matter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561745/how-to-fuzzy-search-json-in-memory-instead-of-mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll suggest a combination of DB's. Before I make some examples for you: Imagine you have your relational model all indexed non relational.

Flat DB/Document DB will do that. Think of a single file to say something like

```
{
    "name": "Down to the river"
    "artist": "BruCe Boss"
    "sql_id": 1391
}
```

Searches on this for 'likeness' become a lot easier and faster. 'Down the hiver', one file.

Now, extend that to all your library of music. In 1 file, your query is just a read on the 1 file with that info. Its a document that indexes your database. The query is faster than reading all records etc, and the result has the SQL id to just go read.

It enriches your current database with more small info that people search for, making queries faster.

I'll edit with a good example but above should get the mains of it.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how this will speed up my algorithm. Correct me if I am wrong here: my goal is to narrow down the query results before performing `similar_text` operations on each result, because similar_text is taxing. Why would it be faster to filter the JSON file in memory rather than SELECT * FROM table and filtering that data in memory. It seems like both methods will get the data into memory and the filtering process will be equally slow once there.

Comment: That's fair, SQL db works on a relational level, i have this id of another table i can search and that might have some others to nest beautiful queries. Flat cant do that. Flat/document says hey: Give me a string, ill tell you all the SQL _id's I matched, without  looking through the whole article which is taxing, use it as a search specific extension of your relational database and it is quick. Or consider your sql-db as a string. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12529310 - is a great example of the extreme. Work them together once you know what you want.

Comment: I think that your solution definitely makes the most sense for me. How would I implement a flat DB (json) and get search results from my PHP API?

Comment: Depends on your own API, your SQL is shielded, because its getting all these crazy queries. Your API will control the calls, that's a different question.. I'm a fan of enhancing your DB, others are a fan of making your DB quicker for this particular scenario. They're all absolutely right. You can make it more efficient, but its an XY problem. IMO - DB is just storage. Nothing More.

Comment: I'm still confused on how I can actually go about implementing it. Do I need to install a no-sql database and my PHP will communicate between that no-sql and mySQL?

Comment: I will jump away on implementation

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate the help, I'l post another more specific question and see if anyone has any ideas.