# How to fuzzy search JSON in memory instead of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

`project_row` table with up to 15k rows per `project_id`:

```
ID | source                       |  target     | project_id
----------------------
0  | hello world                  | hola tierra | 2
1  | hello                        | hola        | 2
2  | what                         |             | 2
3  | you                          | tu          | 2
4  | nevermind. I will head home. |             | 2
5  | There are many sentences     |             | 2
   | stored in the source column  |             | 2
   | as well!                     |             | 2
...
```

`glossary_term` table with up to 40k rows per `glossary_id`:

```
ID | source                       |  target               | glossary_id
----------------------
0  | hello world                  | hola tierra           | 2
1  | hello word                   | hola palabra          | 2
2  | what?                        | que?                  | 2
3  | your                         | tu                    | 2
4  | I will head home.            | Me voy a la casa      | 2
5  | There are many sentences     | también hay muchas    | 2
   | stored in the source column  | oraciones almacenadas | 2
   | as well.                     | en la columna fuente  | 2
...
```

I have an 'analysis' feature that basically compiles a summary of the project's source columns. I am OK with it taking up to 5 minutes to complete, because the user only runs it around once a week. But, my current implementation will take HOURS.

```
SELECT * FROM project_row
SELECT * FROM glossary_row WHERE glossary_id = 2

$data = array();

foreach($projectRow as $row){ //Up to 15k results
    //We need to find the best fuzzy match for this row's source in the glossary
    //I do this by looping each glossary term and running similar_text

    $highestMatchPercent = 0;

    $rowSrc = $row["source"];

    foreach($glossaryTerm as $term){ //Up to 40k results
        $termSrc = $term["source"];

        if(abs(strlen($rowSrc) - strlen($termSrc)) > 10) continue; //Added efficiency. If length difference more than 10, don't bother.

        similar_text($rowSrc, $termSrc, $matchPercent);
        if($matchPercent > $highestMatchPercent) $highestMatchPercent = $matchPercent;

        if($highestMatchPercent == 100) break; //Added efficiency
    }

    //Now we have the highest match percent for this row. This is the data that I need for every row.

    if($highestMatchPercent == 100){
        $data["exact"]++;
    } else if($highestMatchPercent > 75){
        $data["fuzzy"]++;
    }else{
        $data["nothing"]++;
    }
    
}

//Now I have the $data variable with a summary of what I need for this project...after many hours of running this process...
```

Of course, this will take ages to complete with 15k rows and 40k glossary terms. This double loop is very taxing. I have tried to figure out ways to limit the MySQL glossary_term results for each row, but I haven't found a good solution there.

I've been told that you can fuzzy search a massive JSON file loaded in memory MUCH faster than selecting that same data from a database and filtering in PHP. But I have no idea how I would implement something like this. My PHP would somehow need to communicate with the flat DB and query results from it.

Any ideas?