# Partial compare of string using Mongodb aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I've added about 5000 questions to a collection in my MongoDB database. Now I want to arrange the questions together that are just partially similar like 70% to 80% similar and send them to the frontend.

I tried this below pipeline in mongodb aggregate framework. but it groups questions which are 100% similar.

```
 {
        '$group': {
          '_id': {
            '$toLower': '$question'
          },
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          },
          'allData': {
            '$push': {
              '_id': '$_id',
              'question': '$question',
              'categoryId': '$categoryId',
              'subCategoryId': '$subCategoryId',
              'answers': '$answers',
              'solution': '$solution',
              'createdAt': '$createdAt',
              'updatedAt': '$updatedAt'
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$match': {
          'count': {
            '$gte': 2
          }
        }
      }
```

I want to find the partial similar questions like:

**Example 1:** 
Which sentences are true about earthquakes? 
Which sentences are true about earth quakes?

:::The above two question should be marked as similar.

**Example 2:** 
In which European city, The Volvo Group’s headquarters located? 
In which European city, The Volvo head quarters located?

:::The above two question should be marked as similar as 70 to 80 percent of the question are similar.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387452/) answer your question?

Comment: @FiddlingAway No, as i don't want to manually search every string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $ regex in pipeline to find partial text search

Here the link for documentation:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

```
 syntax:-
 { <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
 { <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
example:-
 { 
 quetion: { $regex: /Which sentences are true about earthquakes/, $options: 'i' 
 } }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).